# how can i fix it "func_addr" function

Tags: c, linux

> do not touch main
> only change `func_addr` & use `void *`

I don't know what should i do.

This is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void  func_addr(double (*f)(double));
int main(void)
{
    func_addr(cos);
    func_addr(main);
    return 0;
}
void func_addr(double (*f)(double))
{
    if(f == cos)
        printf("cos() address :%p\n", f);
    else
        printf("address:%p\n", f);
}
```

how can i fix it

Comment: `**func_addr**` is not valid syntax. If you're trying to do highlighting, you can't do that in code blocks.

Comment: What is it you're supposed to change `func_addr` to do?

Comment: @Barmar My guess is that OP shall fix "warning: passing argument 1 of 'func_addr' from incompatible pointer type" & "expected 'double (*)(double)' but argument is of type 'int (*)(void)'"

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be yet another strange homework task from a teacher that knows little about programming.

So what is the problem?

The problem is that `func_addr` expects a function pointer to a function that takes a double as input and returns a double.

However, `func_addr(main);` pass `main` and `main` doesn't take a double as input - nor does it return a double.

To solve this, pass the function pointer as a void pointer.

Simply do:

```
void  func_addr(double (*f)(double)); --> void  func_addr(void* f);
```

and

```
void func_addr(double (*f)(double)) --> void func_addr(void* f)
```

Then all is good...

(...except that you need a new teacher but we can't solve that for you.)

Comment: Great answer, but wouldn't `function pointer to a function that takes a double as input and returns a double` put hair on your chest? ;-) .Good luck to all!